# Open a pdf with adobe reader existed in Raw folder

Tags: android

I was trying to display a pdf file existed in raw folder in android studio. I followed the code below. But that shows the error
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
How to solve this problem?

```
    String uri = "raw://" + R.raw.science;
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(uri)));
    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(pdfIntent);
```

Comment: I think your string  url is wrong.

Comment: how to set that url?

Comment: You cannot open the pdf file directly from the assets folder.You first have to write the file to sd card from assets folder and then read it from sd card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : Copy your pdf from raw to sd card .
Make sure about permission for copy pdf inside sd card:
**WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and
 **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

Example code:

```
public static String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ExampleDir/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 CopyPDFFromAssets();
}
```

Make a method:`CopyPDFFromAssets()`

```
 private void CopyPDFFromAssets() {
  copyFile(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.science),
   new FileOutputStream(new File(dirPath, "my_pdf.pdf")));

  File pdfFile = new File(dirPath, "my_pdf.pdf");
  Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");

  try {
   startActivity(intent);
  } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "No Application Available to View PDF",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

 } catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.toString();
 }

 }
```

Then create method:`copyFile()`:

```
private void copyFile(InputStream in , OutputStream out) throws IOException {
 try {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int read;
  while ((read = in .read(buffer)) != -1) {
   out.write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
 } catch (Exception exp) {

 }    
}
```